# Why does this sorting doesn't work ? (C)

Tags: c, sorting, selection-sort

I am trying to create a sorting method based on selection sort algorithm
With this current code, the array [10, 9, 8 .. 1] is "sorted" to 
[9, 8 .. 2, 10, 1]
I mean like, it doesn't even put 10 in the right place

> 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

"sorted" to

> 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 10 1

What's the problem ?

```
void selectionSort(int array[], int length)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, temp = 0, swap = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        temp = i;
        for(j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if(array[temp] > array[j])
            {
                temp = j;
            }
        }
        swap = array[temp];
        array[temp] = array[i];
        array[i] = swap;
    }
}
```

Comment: The *debugger*  is your friend ...

Comment: Logically this is wrong implementation of selection sort.

Comment: This might help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementation

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/Wyntrn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After each iteration of i, the array upto i , should be sorted. You can print the array after each iteration of i and can see the logical error.

Comment: Had to 'j = i' in the start of the loop

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop should be written like

```
for(j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
    ^^^^^^^^^
```